# How to load parquet file into Snowflake database?

Tags: database, parquet, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to load parquet file directly into a snowflake?
If yes - how?

Thanks.

Comment: According to [the Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load.html), yes.

Comment: https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-to-load-terabytes-into-snowflake-speeds-feeds-and-techniques/

Answer (score 9):

Yes it is possible, and best done via S3. Note, the following assumes you have a MY_PARQUET_LOADER table, a STAGE_SCHEMA schema and an S3STAGE defined, and that your parquet files are on the bucket under the /path/ key/folder.

```
  copy into STAGE_SCHEMA.MY_PARQUET_LOADER
     from ( 
       select
       $1
     ,metadata$filename as metadata_filename
     ,metadata$file_row_number as metadata_file_row_number  
     ,current_timestamp() as load_timestamp
       from
  @S3STAGE/path/)
   pattern = '.*.parquet'
  file_format = (
  TYPE = 'PARQUET' 
  SNAPPY_COMPRESSION = TRUE    )
  ON_ERROR = 'SKIP_FILE_1%'
  purge= TRUE;
```

where this exists:

```
create or replace TABLE MY_PARQUET_LOADER (
    RAW VARIANT,
    METADATA_FILENAME VARCHAR(16777216),
    METADATA_FILE_ROW_NUMBER NUMBER(38,0),
    LOAD_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9)
) cluster by (METADATA_FILENAME);
```

Worthwhile to read the fine manual:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Answer (score 1):

I use these 2 sql to create and load the data into table, this may make your life easier

first: use this SQL to create the table sql

```
with cols as (
select COLUMN_NAME || '   ' || TYPE  col
  from table(
    infer_schema(
      location=>'@LANDING/myFile.parquet'
      , file_format=>'LANDING.default_parquet'
      )
  ) 
),
temp as (
    select 'create or replace table myTable (' col1
    union
    select listagg(col, ',') col1
    from cols
    union
    select ') ' col1
)
select listagg(col1) 
from temp
```

Second, use this SQL to create the copy into SQL load the data into table

```
with cols as (
select expression 
  from table(
    infer_schema(
      location=>'@LANDING/myFile.parquet'
      , file_format=>'LANDING.default_parquet'
      )
  )
),
temp as (
    select 'copy into myTable from ( select ' col1
    union
    select listagg(expression, ',') col1
    from cols
    union
    select 'from @LANDING/myFile.parquet ) ' col1
)
select listagg(col1) 
from temp
```

Answer (score 0):

yes
this could be a solution

```
create or replace TABLE MY_PARQUET_LOADER (
    RAW VARIANT,
    METADATA_FILENAME VARCHAR(16777216),
    METADATA_FILE_ROW_NUMBER NUMBER(38,0),
    LOAD_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9)
) cluster by (METADATA_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file format for parquet, [USE_LOGICAL_TYPE = TRUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table#type-parquet) will make sure that time saved as INT (Epoch) will be translated to datetime.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT parquet_ff
  TYPE = parquet
  USE_LOGICAL_TYPE = TRUE;
```

Create table on Snowflake where you [Infer](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema) the schema from parquet file on stage.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE myTable USING TEMPLATE (
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*)) 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORDER_ID)
FROM TABLE (
    INFER_SCHEMA(
      LOCATION=>'@stage/path/to/parquet'
      , FILE_FORMAT=>'parquet_ff'
      )));
```

Copy into the newly created table from parquet file with the option `MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = 'CASE_INSENSITIVE'` to match it by column names. Check other possible options [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table#copy-options-copyoptions).

```
copy into myTable
from @stage/path/to/parquet 
FILE_FORMAT  = parquet_ff
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = 'CASE_INSENSITIVE'
;
```